# namespase в Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony2

Здравствуйте. У меня следующий вопрос - есть ли возможность использовать в Symfony 2 `use namespace` для аннотаций?

Пример

```
namespace classes;
use OtherClass\Photo;

class Place
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Photo") // OtherClass\Photo;
     */
    private $photo;
}
```

Не работает.

Пишет что

```
The target-entity classes\Photo cannot be found in ....
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Если обратиться к документации http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetomany, то там утверждается, что Вы можете не использовать нэймспейсы только в том случае, если и targetEntity и ваша Place-entity находятся в одном неймспейсе. Соответственно попытка привязать entity из другого неймспейса через use вызовет ошибку

Answer (score 1):

В данных аннотациях вам стоит использовать полные имена классов сущностей, т.к.

- это универсально
- никогда не спутается с другим классом

  - при рефакторинге вам будет проще искать такие классы